# Getting notified when the network connection changes in a Cocoa / Obj-C application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, networking, listener

Is there any way to be notified / have your Cocoa application listen for changes in the network connection (disconnect, connect, etc.)? How does something like [HardwareGrowler](http://growl.info/documentation/hardwaregrowler.php) do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the source code for [HardwareGrowler](http://growl.info/documentation/hardwaregrowler.php) (found under `/Extras` in the [source code for Growl](http://growl.info/source.php), I figure that the easiest way would be to use the `NetworkNotifier.m` class and change all calls to `AppDelegate` functions to whatever callbacks you want executed when the network connection changes (and give them credit for their code!).